# how to extract sentences in a csv file based on keywords from another csv file and delete it from the main one

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv

I have 2 csv files one contain sentences as shown bellow

> how are you
>
> I want to die
>
> I was home
>
> I went to sleep at work
>
> he has a bad reputation
>
> it was me who went to him
>
> have  a good sleep home

and the other csv file contain words with frequency as shown bellow

> word   freq
>
> and    500
>
> you    450
>
> me     300
>
> have   250
>
> your   240
>
> sleep  200
>
> work   150
>
> home   100
>
> die    50

I'm trying to extract the sentences based on the words with frequency between 300 and 100 to a new csv file and remove that sentence after extracting from the main csv file, because sometimes repetition will happen when searching for the new keyword or word, that is the  code I managed to build but does not give me the out put I want:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import re
import string
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print("please provide a CSV file to analys")
else:
    fileinput = sys.argv[1]
    dic = sys.argv[2]

wdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, nrows=0).columns[0]
skip = int(wdata.count(' ') == 0)
wdata = pd.read_csv(fileinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)

data = wdata['sentences'].str.replace('[^\w\s]', ' ')
keywords=pd.read_csv(dic)
keywords=keywords.loc[keywords['freq'].between(100, 300, inclusive=False), 'word']
df1 = data[data['sentences'].str.split(expand=True).isin(keywords).any(axis=1)]
#deleted rows by keywords
df2 = data[~data['sentences'].str.split(expand=True).isin(keywords).any(axis=1)]
print(df1)
```

and I don't know how to delete the sentence in the main file after extracting it, the output I'm expecting is something like that

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) for select keywords:

```
keywords=keywords.loc[keywords['freq'].between(100, 300, inclusive=False), 'word']
print (keywords)
3     have
4     your
5    sleep
6     work
Name: word, dtype: object
```

And then select by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

```
df1 = data[data.str.split(expand=True).isin(keywords.tolist()).any(axis=1)]
print (df1)
3    I went to sleep at work
6     have a good sleep home
Name: sentences, dtype: object

#deleted rows by keywords
df2 = data[~data.str.split(expand=True).isin(keywords.tolist()).any(axis=1)]
print (df2)
0                  how are you
1                I want to die
2                   I was home
4      he has a bad reputation
5    it was me who went to him
Name: sentences, dtype: object
```

Comment: what about deleting the sentence from the main file ? after checking each word in the keywords ?

Comment: one question I will be trying this on a big set of data that is why I need the delete part after each keyword search is done so it will not go back and search the whole thing from the beginning that will be very inconvenient and take a lot of time right ? is that doable ?

Comment: sorry for dustrbing not no matching keywords like after searching the first keyword which in our case is **me** and extract all sentences to a new csv file delete all the sentneces that has **me** in it in the main csv file that we are searching before going to the next keyword to search

Comment: I'm checking it now the only part is the deletation

Comment: it gave me this error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: KeyError: 'A'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: is empty no column name in it but I tried something else check my update code it give this error KeyError: 'sentences'

Comment: Series([], Name: sentences, dtype: object)
 it returns an empty series why ?

Comment: let me post the data for you sorry

Comment: or I can give you the data in chat if you can help me more will be glad man

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207048/discussion-between-programming-freak-and-jezrael).

Comment: @jezreal any ideas why it returns this warning when saving to csv ? newtest.py:24: FutureWarning: The signature of `Series.to_csv` was aligned to that of `DataFrame.to_csv`, and argument 'header' will change its default value from False to True: please pass an explicit value to suppress this warning.
  newdata.to_csv("new_data.csv", index=False)

Comment: @programmingfreak - Can you try `newdata.to_csv("new_data.csv", index=False, header=False)` ?